# Overflow hidden and position absolute for child element issue

Tags: html, css

I have a problem with my website https://kudatoday.kz/ where I'm trying to make my slide in menu visible with `overflow:hidden` on the parent element.

I tried to set `position:absolute` to `.slide-in-menu` and `position:absolute` to header element however it didn't help.

My slide in menu is still hidden. I used `overflow:hidden` just to hide the white blank space on the right, because it appeared once I've created side in menu.

Could you please take a look?

What it should be and what we have:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put `overflow-x:hidden` in the `<body>` tag and then remove `overflow:hidden` from the css `et_pb_section_0_tb_header` in the header `<div>` that is causing the slide in menu to be clipped.

That should solve the clipping issue.

You also need to change `position:absolute` to `position:fixed` in the `.et_pb_row_1_tb_header` css for the slide in menu because it currently scrolls the slide in menu when you scroll the main web page.

Comment: Thank you very very much! Now I understand the logic.